# string pattern replacement in bash

Tags: bash

Using bash, I have a string:

```
str='a $s'
echo ${str/\$/\$a}
# a $as
str='a $1'
echo ${str/\$/\$a}
# a $a1
```

How modify pattern that replacement performs only if word starts with a letter?

I want

```
str='a $s'
echo ${str/??/??}
# a $as
str='a $1'
echo ${str/??/??}
# a $1
```

Answer (score 1):

This would have been trivial if the regex support in Bash allowed [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The solution would then simply be `${str/\$(?=[a-zA-Z])/\$a}`. Unfortunately, that is not the case.

You can still do it if you don't might using `sed`.

```
str='a $s'
echo $str | sed 's/\$\([a-zA-Z]\)/\$a\1/g' # gives you a $as

str='a $1'
echo $str | sed 's/\$\([a-zA-Z]\)/\$a\1/g' # gives you a $1
```

`\$\([a-zA-Z]\)` matches `$` followed by an alphabet and store the alphabet. If a match is found, it is replaced with `$a` followed by the stored alphabet (`\1`). For more details, [see this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4).

The trailing `g` means it will match all occurrences in the string. Remove that if you only want to only replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IF to check if any any letter follows the dollar sign and in case do the replacement:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ \$[[:alpha:]] ]]; then 
    echo ${str/$/\$a}; 
else 
    echo $str; 
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Demonstration:

```
for str in 'a $1' 'a $s'
do
    [[ $str =~ \$([[:alpha:]]) ]]
    echo ${str/\$/\$${BASH_REMATCH[1]:+a}}
done
```

Result:

```
a $1
a $as
```